# Is it possible to remount a socket in Docker w/o container restart?

Tags: docker, mount

While obviously it's easy to restart a container I still would like to avoid if possible. I have five containers which has the same socket mounted into them. If I restart the service providing the socket it (obviously?) breaks so I think I need to remounte the socket. How could I do that?

Comment: Instead of sharing the socket itself, share a directory that contains the socket.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I just had my first emergency mysql restart and this doesn't work, the directory is empty after restart despite the host directory contains the new sockets.